# The file name must end with .xml while creating a signed apk

Tags: android, android-studio

I have to create a signed apk so I have created a keystore.jks etc.

But when I try to generate the apk I have this error :

```
The file name must end with .xml
```

I don't know how it's work ?

Thank's

Comment: Likely you have a misplaced file in some of your `res` folders.

Comment: @laalto yes, where do I have to place it ?

Comment: You should put the full error message in your question. It likely says which file the error refers to.

Comment: @laalto post a answer, you solve my problem

Comment: Done. The question didn't have too may details so the answer is also quite thin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a misplaced file in under `res` that is not a resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for me this is because of when I made a new app just when Google changed the way the app icon is worked on.  So I just used Image Asset Studio in Android Studio and all is good now.